# Вопрос с запятыми

Tags: запятые

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении:

Бери, не важно где мы это взяли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После «не важно» тоже нужна запятая: «не важно» — это отдельная грамматическая основа.